# Fitnesse: __EXCEPTION__:java.lang.NullPointerException at fixtures

Tags: java, fixtures, slim, fitnesse

I am working with fitnesse(20140630)+maven

But when I run my test I get exception:

> **EXCEPTION**:java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.playtech.openapi.core.fitnesse.tests.Fixtures.createContext(Fixtures.java:14) [file:/D:/FitnesseTests/IntegrationTestsMobileAdmin/com-playtech-openapi-frontend-services/com.playtech.openapi.core.fitnesse.tests/target/classes/]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
>       at fitnesse.slim.fixtureInteraction.DefaultInteraction.methodInvoke(DefaultInteraction.java:16) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
>       at fitnesse.slim.MethodExecutor.callMethod(MethodExecutor.java:43) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
>       at fitnesse.slim.MethodExecutor.invokeMethod(MethodExecutor.java:30) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
>       at fitnesse.slim.MethodExecutor.findAndInvoke(MethodExecutor.java:52) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
>       at fitnesse.slim.FixtureMethodExecutor.execute(FixtureMethodExecutor.java:20) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
>       at fitnesse.slim.StatementExecutor.getMethodExecutionResult(StatementExecutor.java:121) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
>       at fitnesse.slim.StatementExecutor.callAndAssign(StatementExecutor.java:109) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
>       at fitnesse.slim.instructions.CallAndAssignInstruction.executeInternal(CallAndAssignInstruction.java:38) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
>       at fitnesse.slim.instructions.Instruction.execute(Instruction.java:30) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
>       at fitnesse.slim.ListExecutor$Executive.executeStatement(ListExecutor.java:50) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
>       at fitnesse.slim.ListExecutor$Executive.executeStatements(ListExecutor.java:44) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
>       at fitnesse.slim.ListExecutor.execute(ListExecutor.java:84) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
>       at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.executeInstructions(SlimServer.java:107) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
>       at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.processTheInstructions(SlimServer.java:94) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
>       at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.processOneSetOfInstructions(SlimServer.java:68) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
>       at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.tryProcessInstructions(SlimServer.java:54) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
>       at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.serve(SlimServer.java:40) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
>       at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.handle(SlimService.java:164) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
>       at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.acceptOne(SlimService.java:172) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
>       at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.accept(SlimService.java:134) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
>       at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.startWithFactory(SlimService.java:65) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]
>       at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.main(SlimService.java:51) [fitnesse-standalone.jar]

---

**This is my fitnesse content**

> !contents -R2 -g -p -f -h
>
> !define TEST_SYSTEM {slim} !path
>   D:\FitnesseTests\IntegrationTestsMobileAdmin\com-playtech-openapi-frontend-services\com.playtech.openapi.core.fitnesse.tests\target\classes
>
> !pomFile
>   D:\FitnesseTests\IntegrationTestsMobileAdmin\com-playtech-openapi-frontend-services\com.playtech.openapi.core.fitnesse.tests\pom.xml@compile
>
> |import| |com.playtech.openapi.core.fitnesse.tests|
>
> !define COLLAPSE_SETUP {true}
>
> !define COLLAPSE_TEARDOWN {true}
>
> !| Script | com.playtech.openapi.core.fitnesse.tests.Fixtures |
>   |$CONTEXT=| createContext|

This is my Java code

```
public class Tests extends AbstractClientIT {

    public String createContext(){
        return "1234567";
    }
}


public class Fixtures {

    private Tests service2;


    public String createContext () throws RemoteException {
        return service2.createContext();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String createContext () throws RemoteException {
    return service2.createContext();
}
```

service2 has not been initialized so this is your NPE

Answer (score 0):

I am new in working with FitNesse, but today I just found this paragraph on "Test Driven .NET Development with FitNesse" book, page 24:

If you created a page (or tried to create one) and got a NullPointerException error, or the page is just not appearing, you chose a wrong name. FitNesse considers only CamelCase words as valid page names and is strict about this. The page name must start with a capital letter and contain at least one more capital letter. There is one more issue to watch out for: consecutive capital letters. FitNesse does not like them. So the capital letters in a page name must be separated by at least one lower-case letter. This convention causes a lot of headaches to FitNesse newbies, but after a while you'll get used to it.